# <int:pk> url mapping error , <int:pk> not passing

Tags: django, url-mapping

Here is my html link from where I want to use `<int:pk>`

```
<a href= "/main/profile/edit/{{ user.myprofile.id }}" >Edit Profile</a>
```

When I click on the link I get a url mapping error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/profile/edit/
Using the URLconf defined in lunarcodes.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

  main/ home/
  main/ profile/
  main/ feed/
  main/ profile/edit/<int:pk>
```

here is my urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [ 

path('profile/edit/<int:pk>', views.MyProfileUpdateView.as_view(success_url="/main/profile")),

    ]
```

this is my views.py,

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")    
class MyProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = MyProfile
fields = ["name", "description", "pic"]
```

this is my models.py,

```
class MyProfile(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=CASCADE)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
pic= models.ImageField(upload_to = "images\\", null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.user
```

I myself couldn't understand the problem properly as I am beginner.

Comment: The URL in the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/profile/edit/` error message is missing the id. That means that `{{ user.myprofile.id }}` isn't showing the profile id as expected. To figure out why, you need to look at the view that renders the template with that link. If that link is inside a loop, e.g. `{% for user in users %}`, then please include that in your question as well.

Comment: @ishan Please share the view which renders this anchor tag. I mean the Details/Listing view by which this anchor tag is rendered to some html